# Windows Authentication Asp.net know how

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, sqlexception

I am building an intranet web application using Asp.net C# and trying to use Windows Authentication. I enabled Windows Authentication in IIS 7.5. I was able to login using the same user name and password to login to my windows machine.

But when I try to access the database. I get this message "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'USER\HCSA167$'."

What can I do to enable to access the database?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without code showing what you are trying to do, I'm going to have to make some assumptions.

It looks like you've created an ASP.NET application that uses Windows authentication to authenticate the user. Then from the code behind, you are calling into a SQL Server database and get the error.

The account in the error message appears to be a network service account for the machine making the SQL connection. You may want to give that machine account a [login in SQL Server](http://v) to make this work.

ASP.NET does not automatically impersonate the logged in user. If you want to authenticate the SQL call with the user's credentials, look at [this section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx#paght000008_trustedsubsystems) in the linked article below.

For more information on SQL Server and Windows authentication see these links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx
  http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_logins_and_users.html